# Using a ForeignCollection

Tags: android, ormlite, foreign-collection

My entity contains the following private `ForeignCollection` attribute:

```
@ForeignCollectionField
private ForeignCollection<Order> orderCollection;

private List<Order> orderList;
```

What is the best way or usual way to avoid a having a caller use a `ForeignCollection`?  Is there any neat way to return the `Collections` data to a caller?

How does the following method look?  It allows a caller to access the data via a `List`. Would you recommend doing it this way?

```
public List<Order> getOrders() {
    if (orderList == null) {
        orderList = new ArrayList<Order>();
        for (Order order : orderCollection) {
            orderList.add(order);
        }
    }
    return orderList;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's ok to change the signature to `Collection` rather than `List`, you could try using [Collections.unmodifiableCollection()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableCollection%28java.util.Collection%29).

```
public Collection<Order> getOrders()
{
    return Collections.unmodifiableCollection(orderCollection);
}
```

Otherwise, your approach of using a lazy member variable is fine (provided you don't need synchronization). Also, note that you can just use the constructor of `ArrayList` to copy the values from the source collection:

```
orderList = new ArrayList<Order>(orderCollection);
```

Comment: accepted this answer but hoping a better solution comes along.